# Problem using linq to concat two collections

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class A
{
   public bool Selected;
   public DateTime CreateDate;
}
```

I have a collection of A, let call it Coll, i want to do:

```
Coll.Where(a => a.Selected).Concat(Coll.Where(a => !a.Selected)
.OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate))
```

This look great, but the result is the same if i remove the order part, because Linq is generating the following string

```
SELECT [t2].[Selected], [t2].[CreateDate]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Selected], [t0].[CreateDate]
    FROM [dbo].[A] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[Selected] = 1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [t2].[Selected], [t2].[CreateDate]
    FROM [dbo].[A] AS [t1]
    WHERE (NOT ([t1].[Selected] = 1)) 
    ) 
AS [t2]
```

As you can see the OrderBy dissapear in the sql sintax generated by linq, if someone could help with this would be great.

Comment: Do you have nulls on the Selected column?

Comment: No, there is not null in any of this column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a parenthesis mismatch, as [pointed out by vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970814/problem-using-linq-to-concat-two-collections/3970852#3970852).  This is easier to see if you split the lines:

```
Coll
   .Where(a => a.Selected)
   .Concat( 
        Coll.Where(a => !a.Selected).OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)
      )
```

And should be:

```
Coll
   .Where(a => a.Selected)
   .Concat(
       Coll.Where(a => !a.Selected)
      )
   .OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)
```

However, this makes no sense.  You're trying to concat all of the members where a.Selected is true with the ones where it's false - basically selecting the entire collection.  You can just select everything (removing the concat) and get the same result:

```
Coll.OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)
```

---

Edit in response to comments:

> I split in two case because i want the items "Selected" first in the collection resulted

In this case, you should do:

```
Coll.OrderByDescending(a => a.Selected).ThenBy(a => a.CreateDate)
```

Comment: my assumption was that he simplified the code in the example, but you're quite right.

Comment: I split in two case because i want the items "Selected" first in the collection resulted

Comment: @Deumber: I edited to show you a better option for that,as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to order the entire collection? if so, I think a parenthesis is placed in the wrong spot (fragment below is untested):

`Coll.Where(a => a.Selected).Concat(Coll.Where(a => !a.Selected)).OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate)`

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could try:

```
query1.Concat(query2).OrderBy(selector)
```

as in TSQL it doesn't make sense to filter just *part* of a query. If you need the first set first, perhaps introduce a dummy value:

```
query1.Select(row => new {x=1,row})
  .Concat(query2.Select(row => new {x=2,row}))
  .OrderBy(tmp => tmp.x)
  .ThenBy(tmp => tmp.row.whatever)
  .Select(tmp => tmp.row);
```